# Set HSQLDB data type in hibernate configuration files?

Tags: hsqldb

I am trying to create an in-memory DB using HSQLDB 2.2.5. We are also using Hibernate. The problem is that our Domain Objects are annotated for Oracle. We generate the HBM files from the POJOs. Hence I am getting "type not found or user lack privileges: NUMBER" errors when I attempt to run against HSQLDB. HSQL 2.2.5 doesn't support NUMBER, only NUMERIC.

Is there any way in the hibernate configuration file or hibernate.properties to tell HSQL to treat NUMBER as NUMERIC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this version of HSQLDB supports the Oracle syntax compatibility and accepts MUMBER in this mode, plust many other Oracle-specific features. See the Guide for details.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#N14266

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I just need to add sql.syntax_ora=true to my URL.